# Django: How to resolve errors when switching django version?

Tags: python, django, migration

I am working on a django project which is a cms (geonode: http://geonode.org/) and uses django 1.6.11
But I am facing some problems with migrations in django 1.6.11

So I want to switch from django 1.6.11 to django 1.8 and I installed django 1.8. But after installing django 1.8 when I am trying to run the server it gives me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ImportError: No module named utils.version
```

Also

```
from django.db.models.related import RelatedObject
ImportError: No module named related
```

Can anyone help me?? I want to replace django 1.6 and want to migrate 1.8

Comment: In a comment to a deleted answer, you happen to mention that this problem is happening in a third-party project, "polymorphic". That would be important information in the question itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry but could not understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django 1.8 Changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.8/#model-attribute-on-private-model-relations) this API has been changed.

Check the release notes of [1.8 release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.8/) (and preferably [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.7/) too) to know the major changes in the releases since 1.6